# Extensions for unity

Tags: unity, unity-dash

Users of Gnome can write and upload extensions for customisation, as can be seen here https://extensions.gnome.org/. Is there anything similar for Unity? I haven't been able to find anything.

I know I can switch to Gnome but I want this in Unity.

Comment: As far as  know, gnome shell is incompatible with unity

Comment: Yes, I know. I was wondering if there were extensions for Unity